# Twitter web intent not prepending @ sign to `via` parameter

Tags: ios, twitter, mobile-website, ios-universal-links

I am using a simple Twitter [web intent](https://dev.twitter.com/web/intents) (hyperlink) from a mobile-focused website that is intended to allow the visitor to compose a tweet pointing back to a page on my site. The intent is populated with various parameters, including a `via` parameter that holds a Twitter handle:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=...&via=MyTwitterHandle
```

When the link is clicked on most platforms, it opens twitter.com in the browser, and everything works as expected. The Twitter compose dialog opens with all of the information from the link prepopulated.

[image: Working as expected on mobile web]

However, on iOS 9 devices that have Twitter installed, something's wrong. As expected with Universal Links, the native Twitter app handles the click. But when it loads, the `via` parameter (which holds my Twitter username) is populated without the @ sign prepended. The native compose dialog looks something like this:

[image]

Because the @ character is not prepended, Twitter doesn't recognize it as a username.

I've found [two](https://twittercommunity.com/t/tweet-web-intent-twitter-app-for-ios-conflicts/56297/1) [mentions](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-sharing-misses-when-swtiching-from-a-browser-to-the-app-on-ios/59252) of this problem on Twitter's developer site, but no solutions.

While contrary to the [documentation for the Tweet Intent](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent), I've tried including the `@` sign in the `via` parameter itself, but that results in `@@` in the very common case where the mobile web Twitter interface is used.

What other solutions do I have for a very simple Tweet intent that includes the `via` parameter and works across all major mobile platforms?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but I just tried and it seems like the problem is fixed as of 17th March 2016!